# No puedo verificar la conexión con el servidor

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap

Alguien me puede ayudar, estoy intentando validar que exista comunicacion con el servidor, tengo un archivo llamado response.php que si se logra conectar este da como mensaje en tipo json "OK" si no simplemente no envia nada.
me esta enviando el "OK" y lo estoy recibiendo a traves de ajax, y le paso el "OK" a una variable global de tipo string por lo que en esa variable valido, dentro de la funcion recibe el ok pero cuando afuera de la funcion siempre queda vacia que me falta o que estoy haciendo mal ? dejo una imagen de referencia gracias por la ayuda

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: se me fue en la imagen pero al final del codigo recibo por consola el valor de la variable;                                                                                                                  console.log('conectado? = ' + conectado);

Comment: Hola David y bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que conozcas como elaborar una pregunta que sea bien recibida por la comunidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu error al parecer es que no estas tomando en cuenta que ajax se resuelve de manera asíncrona. Imagino que tu código donde muestras "console.log('conectado? = ' + conectado)" esta fuera de la función success, la cual se ejecuta primero y una vez el ajax obtiene respuesta recién se le asigna el valor "OK" a la variable conectado pero no hace nada con ella debido a que ya se ejecuto el log de conectado por lo tal imprime la variable conectado en blanco, debes colocar todas las sentencias que desees se ejecuten dentro de la variable success

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda Jhony, según tu respuesta a mi pregunta sabia que podía hacerlo de esa manera solo que quería pasarle el valor a una variable estando fuera de esa función pero lo hice como tu me lo indicaste y si funciono... muchas gracias..